# Create plotly scattermapbox from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, mapbox

I would like to create a scattermapbox for indonesia for various statistics (population, GDP, etc.) on a regional basis.
I am working with a geopandas file from [github](https://github.com/superpikar/indonesia-geojson/blob/master/indonesia-en.geojson).

The [example](https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/) on the plotly website creates multiple files for each layer and then uses the github link as source.

```
#republican counties
source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/florida-red-data.json'  
#democrat counties
source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/florida-blue-data.json'
```

My question therefore is, how can I use the pandas dataframe to create layer dict for every region and use that as a source (also colouring of each region by specific values in other dataframes).
Should that not be possible at all and it is necessary to create a seperate file for each region how would I do that? My attempt (lines 16-20) doesn't seem to work

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import string
import plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattermapbox, Layout
ID_regions = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N1x0/indonesia-geojson/master/indonesia-edit.geojson')

region_names = []

for region in ID_regions['features']:
    region_names.append(state['properties']['name'])

print(region_names)

#This shit creates json and doesn't work
def create_region_files():
    for i in range(len(ID_regions)):
        region_data = ID_regions.iloc[i,:]
        region_data.to_json(f'C:\\Users\\nicho\\Desktop\\Waste Management\\Map_Maker\\ID_regions\\{region_names[i]}.json')
        i += 1


def create_Chloropleth():
    mapbox_access_token = 'My Access Key'

    data = [
        Scattermapbox(
            lat=['45.5017'],
            lon=['-73.5673'],
            mode='markers',
        )
    ]
    layout = Layout(
        height=900,
        autosize=True,
        showlegend=False,
        hovermode='closest',
        mapbox=dict(
            layers=[
                dict(
                    sourcetype = 'geojson',
                    source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N1x0/indonesia-geojson/master/indonesia-edit.geojson',
                    type = 'fill',
                    color = 'green'
                ),
                dict(
                    sourcetype = 'geojson',
                    source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N1x0/indonesia-geojson/master/west-sulawesi.json',
                    type = ' fill',
                    color = 'red',
                )
            ],
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=0.7893,
                lon=113.9213
            ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=4.5,
            style='light'
        ),
    )

    fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
    plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Chloropleth_Province_Population.html')

create_Chloropleth()
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok took me a while but i figured it all out. Big thanks to [Emma Grimaldi](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-interactive-map-plots-with-plotly-7b57e889239a) over at Medium and [Vince Pota](http://vincepota.com/plotly_choropleth_map.html). Their posts were what helped me through most of it. 
So here the answers to my own question in order:

1. It is not necessary to create an individual file for each region. I.e. you can use a pandas dataframe to match names of the regions in the json and that'll work just fine.

`with open('indonesia-en.geojson') as f:
     geojson = json.load(f)`

```
def make_sources(downsample = 0):
    sources = []
    geojson_copy = copy.deepcopy(geojson['features']) # do not overwrite the original file
    for feature in geojson_copy:

        if downsample > 0:
            coords = np.array(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0])
            coords = coords[::downsample]
            feature['geometry']['coordinates'] = [[coords]]

        sources.append(dict(type = 'FeatureCollection',
                            features = [feature])
                      )
    return sources
```

So you just extract the coordinates from the geojson and append them to a a list of dicts`[{}]`.

2. How to use this list to dynamically create layers:

```py
    MAPBOX_APIKEY = "Your API Key"
    data = dict(type='scattermapbox',
                lat=lats,
                lon=lons,
                mode='markers',
                text=hover_text,
                marker=dict(size=1,
                            color=scatter_colors,
                            showscale = True,
                            cmin = minpop/1000000,
                            cmax = maxpop/1000000,
                            colorscale = colorscale,
                            colorbar = dict(
                            title='Population in Millions'
                            )
                           ),
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='text'
                 )

    layers=([dict(sourcetype = 'geojson',
                  source =sources[k],
                  below="water",
                  type = 'line',    # the borders
                  line = dict(width = 1),
                  color = 'black',
                  ) for k in range(n_provinces) # where n_provinces = len(geojson['features'])
              ] +

            [dict(sourcetype = 'geojson',
                  source =sources[k],
                  type = 'fill',   # the area inside the borders
                  color = scatter_colors[k],
                  opacity=0.8
                 ) for k in range(n_provinces)  # where n_provinces = len(geojson['features'])
             ]
            )
```

So the solution here is too set  `sources = sources[k]` I.e. the list with the dict of lat/long values created in `make_sources()`

3. How to color the layers accordingly `color=scatter_colors[k]`

Using the linked example I used 3 functions

3.1   `scalarmappable`

```
#sets colors based on min and max values
def scalarmappable(cmap, cmin, cmax):
        colormap = cm.get_cmap(cmap)
        norm = Normalize(vmin=cmin, vmax=cmax+(cmax*0.10)) #vmax get's increased 10 percent because otherwise the most populous region doesnt get colored
        return cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=colormap)
```

3.2 `scatter_colors`

```
#uses matplotlib to create colors based on values and sets grey for isnan value
def get_scatter_colors(sm, df):
grey = 'rgba(128,128,128,1)'
return ['rgba' + str(sm.to_rgba(m, bytes = True, alpha = 1)) if not np.isnan(m) else grey for m in df]
```

3.3 `colorscale`

```
#defines horizontal range and corresponding values for colorscale
def get_colorscale(sm, df, cmin, cmax):
    xrange = np.linspace(0, 1, len(df))
    values = np.linspace(cmin, cmax, len(df))

    return [[i, 'rgba' + str(sm.to_rgba(v, bytes = True))] for i,v in zip(xrange, values) ]
```

Then variables using the functions are set

```
#assigning values
colormap = 'nipy_spectral'
minpop = stats['population'].min()
maxpop = stats['population'].max()
sources = make_sources(downsample=0)
lons, lats = get_centers()

sm = scalarmappable(colormap, minpop, maxpop)
scatter_colors = get_scatter_colors(sm, stats['population'])
colorscale = get_colorscale(sm, stats, minpop, maxpop)
hover_text = get_hover_text(stats['population'])
```

So if anyone had some problems with this answer can help you progress :)